# Dynamics CRM Option Set Duplicated on Solution Import

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013

Scenario, in error a new option set label of "Update" was added with value 100,000,000 to a field in the default managed solution in Production.

Identical label with value 866,100,002 was added to same field in the unmanaged Development Solution, when latest round of export and import occurred a duplicate option set label for "Update" was added to the managed solution in Production.

I now have data in the tables with both values and  duplicate labels in the managed solution.

Question: how to unwind this mess - can I delete the label relating to value 100,000,000 seeing how it will just get duplicated upon the next solution import?

What happens to the data in the Database - is there a way to update the recorded values of 100,000,000 to a correct 866,100,002?

Answer (score 2):

Do an Advanced Find for records having optionset value `100,000,000`, export to excel (with selected option to reimport). Bulk update the exported records to the correct `866,100,002` optionset value & reimport it. This is first thing, it will correct the data.

Then you can delete the dupe label in picklist & monitor for future imports.

Test it in lower environments. Take solution/database backup as a precaution.